# Apply CSS when browser is maximized?

Tags: html, css

I have a login page that runs fine when the browser is maximized. But when i resize it, the elements start to wander around. I've done a bit of research and i found this:

```
#wrapper { /*It will contain all the elements.*/
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   min-height: 500px;
   min-width: 500px;
}
```

It works but since i'm setting a min-height and min-width, some screen resolutions will force the browser to apply the scroll bars, even if it is maximized. Is there a way to show the scrollbars only when the user resizes the browser?

Comment: You can use some mediaqueries. @media screen and (min-width: 500px) { }. CSS inside this will only apply when browser size in more than 500px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not just set min-height to 400px?

this will allow all resolutions to display the page without scrollbars

(smallest res: 640x460) --> `640 px` width and `460 px` height.

overall you cannot force a browser to not display scrollbars, while maintaining scroll functionality (at least not without some framework)

Comment: Well, i guess i'll set it to 1024x768....i think that the probability of the users of having a 640x480 monitor is pretty small xD
Thanks!

Comment: There are plenty of devices out there that are smaller than 400px (hint:  they fit in the palm of your hand).

Comment: @cimmanon well that is a whole different story, because they have 2 Viewports, see http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports2.html thus your argument is invalid... Jvam: care the inner browser res is not the screen res!!

Comment: That article is quite old and hardly relevant here.  What's the difference between a browser that's maximized and 400px wide vs a browser that's not maximized and 400px wide?

Comment: @cimmanon none (even though there will be no maximized browser who is 400px wide except in a VM), and how would it affect my solution if he is maximized or not?

Comment: Well, i've tested it on IE9 and google chrome (most recent version) and it works, but not on firefox (most recent)....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the overflow setting to hide and show scrollbars. More here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp There's no way to detect that a user has resized their browser using just HTML/CSS. You could do it with javascript but you probably don't want to write your page styles using javascript. You can however use media queries to apply different css rules at different document widths. More here: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/

Answer (score 0):

If your content allows it, you could just leave things a little more flexible, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
div {background: red; width: 40em; padding: 1em; margin: 0 auto; max-width: 100%;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div>
    <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```